# Can't get the while loop based on boolean statements to run properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, while-loop

I can't get the right logic behind the boolean statements so that the function runs.

I'm basing my code on LPTHW exercise 35. I've basically just copied the structure of that exercise and tried to make it work.
I wanted to test and see if I could make the while loop work.

If I type Yes with capitol Y, it prints "Put on the raincoat, m..", but it wont run function rain(). 
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex35_2.py", line 52, in <module>
    temp ()
  File "ex35_2.py", line 12, in temp
    wool()
  File "ex35_2.py", line 29, in wool
    rain()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Also, the else-condition exits the program, I see that. But what if I wanted it to start at the top again? That it goes in a loop until it either gets Yes or No?

```
def wool():
    print "OK, so it is pretty cold outside!"
    print "Put on the wool."
    print "But is it raining?"
    rain = True

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "Yes": #if written with "Yes", it prints "Put on the.." 
            print "Put on the rain coat, m*!" 
            rain()
        elif next == "Yes" and rain:
            print "It is raining, but I dont wanna stress with the rain coat!"
        elif next == "No" and not rain: #how do I activate this condition since rain = True?
            print "You dont need a raincoat."
            march("With wool and no raincoat.")
        else:
            print "You should make a choice." #this is the only output. 
        exit(0)
```

When I give other user input, it goes straight to the else-statement.

```
You should make a choice.
```

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent. Please make sure that the indentation in the code you show is what it really is.

Comment: And how could you call `rain` when you a couple of lines before define it as a boolean variable (with `rain = True`)? Do you *also* have a function called `rain` (that you don't show us)? This is why it's so important that you create a [mcve] to show us. Also read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you load a module or define the function `rain()` somewhere before calling the `wool()` function.

So, what's happening now, is that in the moment you declare the variable `rain = True` **the local variable definition takes precedence over your prior function definition**. This implies, rather then calling the function `rain()` you 'call' the variable `rain`.

In order to avoid this make sure to keep track of your namespace. If you import a module containing `rain`, you can import the entire module and then use `module_name.rain()`.

If you just define the function within the script, you need to rename either the function or the variable. For example replace `rain = True` by `it_is_raining = True`

While this explains why `rain()` is not called, you also need to be careful about the order of your `if ... elif ...` construction. If you enter `'Yes'`, you will always execute the code after the if statement, and the subsequent conditions are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Your program prints out the else-statement, because you haven't indented the content inside your else and elif. Right now, "You should make a choice" is printed outside your if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to correct the code and give some advice:

```
def wool():
    print "OK, so it is pretty cold outside!"
    print "Put on the wool."
    print "But is it raining?"
    rain = True

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "Yes": #if written with "Yes", it prints "Put on the.." 
            print "Put on the rain coat!" 
            rain()
        elif next == "Yes" and rain: #!!!
            print "It is raining, but I dont wanna stress with the rain coat!" #!!!
        elif next == "No" and not rain: #how do I activate this condition since rain = True?
            print "You dont need a raincoat."
            march("With wool and no raincoat.")
        else:
            print "You should make a choice." #this is the only output. # !!!
        exit(0)
```

Look for #!!!
First one: this elif will never be evaluated, just because if **next == "Yes"** the first if will win, surely. I would change it to:

```
if next == "Yes": #if written with "Yes", it prints "Put on the.."
    if rain:
        print "It is raining, but I dont wanna stress with the rain coat!"
    else:
        print "Put on the rain coat, *****!" 
        rain()
elif next .....
```

Logic behind something here is hidden: you are asking if it's raining, and write down: **rain = True**

> "how do I activate this condition since rain = True?"

well, if user said it's not raining, it's not raining.

I dunno why you are using a pre-setted boolean even if you have user input.

Indentation after else: statement.

Well, you else statement will get every "No" input, because rain is indeed always True.

Thinking that rain boolean is somehow needed:

```
elif next == "No" 
    if rain:
        print("Lie!")
        #maybe rain = False ??
    else:
        print "You dont need a raincoat."
        march("With wool and no raincoat.")
else:
    print "You should make a choice." #this is the only output. # !!!
exit(0)
```